# C# HttpClient specify which cookie container to use on a per request basis

Tags: c#

Is there a way to send requests through HttpClient such that each request/response is linked to a given cookie container? Or some other technique that would allow for cookies to be managed in a user defined way, ie username/pw, for a particular domain name.

The current way I do it is to instantiate a new Httpclient class for every username/login, but was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: what you have tried

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding your question, I believe you would need to create a new CookieContainer and HttpClient instance for each domain you are hoping to interact with.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using(var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
{
  using(var client = new HttpClient(handler))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you understood me correctly. In fact, this is the exact way I am dealing with this issue. Always seemed inefficient

Comment: Why does it seem inefficient? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I gave a use case in my original question, multiple logins on the same domain name.

Comment: Inefficient for several reasons. Instantiating several of the same objects when the only difference is the cookie container linked to it. Additionally, every instance of HttpClient opens up its own socket connection if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Instantiating a new HttpClient for each request is not what was intended according to the docs. "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Especially in server applications, creating a new HttpClient instance for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client. So, I am struggling with the same question as @cubesnyc

Comment: HttpClient's should live for the lifetime of the application.  While this works, it will result in an unstable app.